# Iphone6 and 6s(9.3 version) real devices are not working in appium(1.5.3) tool on mac(OS X El Capitan -10.11.4 version).And we are using xcode -7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, selenium-webdriver, appium

Please find below error log. Error is showing as below

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find
>   a device to launch. You requested 'iPhone (9.3)', but the available
>   devices were: ["Apple TV 1080p (9.2)
>   [C0018F88-126A-44FC-B30E-0BE88297A86E] (Simulator)","Test (8.1)
>   [AA98A16E-41EB-4A35-B72F-6988676F9EC3] (Simulator)","iPad 2 (8.1)
>   [C2460104-58F5-42B7-A51A-2BEE61D52F20] (Simulator)","iPad 2 (8.4)
>   [C92A7395-9758-4A95-8656-ECF2988C1195] (Simulator)","iPad 2 (9.3)
>   [C62B64FF-9942-44F7-BF7A-7A8AAF13A4F6] (Simulator)","iPad Air (8.1)
>   [1476073B-AC4A-4483-870A-170E1D2BAA2F] (Simulator)","iPad Air (8.4)
>   [982350B7-7159-4AB6-BEE3-B8457E7B5455] (Simulator)","iPad Air (9.3)
>   [E79CB848-CE03-4C37-A96B-8551B8127AE7] (Simulator)","iPad Air 2 (9.3)
>   [0080C3DF-CBF4-422D-8C97-9C902ACCA84B] (Simulator)","iPad Pro (9.3)
>   [0E0CDFBD-A343-422F-A95A-BF1340F8F24C] (Simulator)","iPad Retina (8.1)
>   [AB5B9546-E74E-499E-9A74-DBED6845F2E4] (Simulator)","iPad Retina (8.4)
>   [E099131F-65A3-4C21-8F85-C988F4094C4D] (Simulator)","iPad Retina (9.3)
>   [EAC942D7-77F9-4DDE-9D84-B4DC68148F45] (Simulator)","iPhone 4s (8.1)
>   [2C893F1D-AECE-433B-AA9C-9763D60BE383] (Simulator)","iPhone 4s (8.4)
>   [87EC4666-CA1D-497E-8CEC-411253B07AF7] (Simulator)","iPhone 4s (9.3)
>   [C028CAA4-DE61-4391-AA6F-134377B11543] (Simulator)","iPhone 5 (8.1)
>   [82446C48-9BB8-4108-B72C-5E9F7004B9C3] (Simulator)","iPhone 5 (8.4)
>   [0F680256-CF75-4D73-9738-4DACF4E18853] (Simulator)","iPhone 5 (9.3)
>   [D041D017-79F5-4CD1-8278-768B3B522339] (Simulator)","iPhone 5s (8.1)
>   [244AC4AE-D236-426A-ACD7-1DF23378238B] (Simulator)","iPhone 5s (8.4)
>   [8F88E094-5331-4648-AFD6-195DD051CF1E] (Simulator)","iPhone 5s (9.3)
>   [4488DB16-190B-4E46-92B8-06DD1A01C805] (Simulator)","iPhone 6 (8.1)
>   [481B1832-1A87-4E98-9D74-2A2B7D24764D] (Simulator)","iPhone 6 (8.4)
>   [0E11A31C-AAF5-44F2-9D1A-05B90967FCEB] (Simulator)","iPhone 6 (9.3)
>   [C96F7108-24AD-4E19-9BB4-EDB2DC734D46] (Simulator)","iPhone 6 Plus
>   (8.1) [14666DBC-AAAF-4B39-8E66-52BAA0E3992F] (Simulator)","iPhone 6
>   Plus (8.4) [C461ABD8-E5CB-4014-93C5-C7CC860326E9] (Simulator)","iPhone
>   6 Plus (9.3) [16C3C439-B246-490F-80CA-361CD99F1EB9]
>   (Simulator)","iPhone 6s (9.3) [9CE696EC-FEB8-4B6D-A93C-B9EC3580D085]
>   (Simulator)","iPhone 6s (9.3) + Apple Watch - 38mm (2.2)
>   [ADD11868-8449-4AA3-9D18-2FC290D6AEF4] (Simulator)","iPhone 6s Plus
>   (9.3) [8D389B44-80FD-41B6-BAD8-E3A40A16B41C] (Simulator)","iPhone 6s
>   Plus (9.3) + Apple Watch - 42mm (2.2)
>   [4A93D3D3-CB38-47D3-A339-725E96B58991] (Simulator)"] (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 1.23 seconds Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision:
>   '1af067dbcaedd7d2ab9af5151fc471d363d97193', time: '2016-02-05
>   11:20:57' System info: host: 'vbs-chd-nb96.vserv-it.com', ip:
>   '172.17.3.98', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version:
>   '10.11.4', java.version: '1.8.0_60' Driver info:
>   io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: pleae download and make sure `iPhone (9.3)` is added to your simulators

Comment: iPhone (9.3) already added.

Comment: For real devices, try using the UDID in the desired capabilities object, instead of specifying by device and iOS version.

Comment: we want to execute script in iphone mobile safari browser, so which path we would need to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following capabilities :

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6s (9.3)");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "6gt72bfbi38sehi42"); //change the UDID to your device
// update the name provided by to a one in the list specified in the trace logs
```

Comment: I tried above mentioned code but still getting same issue, same code working on simulator.

Comment: @Sivanandareddy - for real device try and append the `UDID` of the device along with the name of the device

Comment: I was tried with UDID also, still getting below error:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 32.63 seconds

Comment: @Sivanandareddy - that seems to be a different problem from this, several threads over that on SO. Possibly change the app path or format to .ipa.

Comment: we want to execute script in iphone mobile safari browser, so which path we would need to setup.

Answer (score 0):

first, confirm that, u have available device named iPhone 6s in ur device list from

```
xcode -> window -> devices
```

if not than create a new simulator from there by clicking on + button at bottom.

Than make sure, u use the below code:

```
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.3");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6s");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "ur id"); 

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "7.3");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,"Mac");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
```

one more optional thing, in ur appium IOS setting, in Force device option, give the iphone 6s as device

Comment: I was tried with UDID also, still getting below error:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 32.63 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing the correct udid in appium desired capabilities. Before running the script and hit ideviceinfo on terminal and check your udid. If it doesn't work then can you attach the appium log?

Comment: I was tried with UDID also, still getting below error:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 32.63 seconds

Comment: If it is giving the bad app error it means app is not present on given location.

Comment: In your code you have to give the correct path of your build .app

Comment: we want to execute script in iphone mobile safari browser, so which path we would need to setup.

Comment: Then please set capability browser safari. And then execute it.

Comment: Please find below Capabilities,
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability("PlatformVersion", "9.3");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "Device UDID"); 
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6s");
     capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
     capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "safari");